# Assigining controls to arrays in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have created an array square(40) as picturebox.

I have to assign 40 picture boxes in my form to these arrays. All have names like, pb1,pb2 and so on. How to do it by looping?  Or will I have to go by the standard method of assigning them one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through your Forms Control Collection and assign them that way, I would use your Tag Property as an Index.

```
For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cntrl Is PictureBox Then
        square(CInt(cntrl.Tag)) = CType(cntrl, PictureBox)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I didn't really get what you want to say

Comment: Okay. But I want pb1 to be assigned to squares(1), pb2 to squares(2) and so on. Will I be able to do that through this?

Comment: @RohitShinde see my edit. I also am adding an index to your picturebox's Tag Property,  i.e. pb1.Tag = 0, pb2.Tag = 1 .... etc

Comment: @RohitShinde remember arrays in .Net are zero based. what ever your tag is is where in the array it will be assigned.

Comment: @RohitShinde this is also assumes that your pictureboxs are in your Main Form

Comment: My picture boxes are in my main form